# android file path apply image to glide

Tags: android, image, kotlin, android-glide

The library returns a path like this

```
/external/images/media/119
```

If I put it in gilde as it is, an error occurred, so I used the following method

```
fun getPath(uri: Uri, context: Context): String {
            val cursor: Cursor? = context.contentResolver.query(uri, null, null, null, null )

            cursor?.moveToNext()

            val path: String? = cursor?.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("_data"))

            cursor?.close()

            return path?:""
        }
```

This will cause the path to come out as null so the elvis operator will print blanks.

How can I get the address I can put into the glide?

Comment: `library returns a path like this

/external/images/media/119` That is no path but probably the last part of a content scheme. Which library? Show value of your uri. Show content scheme.

Comment: You can use Glide with the uri directly.

Answer (score 0):

I missed

```
content://media/
```

When I add this part and run the method, it works fine.

Comment: You should not add it. You should use the uri as it contains the whole content scheme. Uri.string.

Answer (score -1):

I think I will work for you.

```
val projection = arrayOf(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA)
val cursor = context.contentResolver.query(uri, projection, null, null, null)
var path = ""

cursor?.let {
    if (it.moveToFirst()) {
        val columnIndex = it.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA)
        path = it.getString(columnIndex)
    }
    it.close()
}

return path
```

Please check and let me know if it works in your case.